# Offline access on iPad to svn diff information

Tags: ios, svn, pdf, offline

I've seen a couple iOS apps that allow access to svn logs, but none as nice as iOctocat is for git.  It appears I could use iOctocat on a network to collect all the data, and then view it offline.  I need to do that for svn, not git.

I'm looking for a way to read svn log commit diffs in an offline state on an eReader (prefer iPad, but could switch to say Kindle Fire if required.)  Is there any OSX software/scripts that can get an svn server log, perform diffs, and output into files for viewing on an iPad, or alternatively, into a PDF that can be viewed darn near anywhere?

I'm trying to get a bit more productive on my 1.5 hour bus ride, and this could help tremendously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to review the logs, you can generate a PDF file easily enough. The command:

```
svn log | enscript -o log.ps
```

makes a PostScript file from the log for the current working directory. You can follow that with:

```
pstopdf log.ps
```

to generate `log.pdf`, a PDF file that contains your Subversion log. You can obviously automate that process to your heart's content. You might even run the process every few hours and post the result on an internal web server where it's easy to grab. You can also make the PDF file that you generate a lot fancier by configuring `enscript`, which has oodles of options (font, margins, columns, headers, footers, etc.) so you can make a really nice looking file.

For convenience, here's a version all on one line:

```
svn log -l 10 | enscript -o - | pstopdf -i -o svnlog.pdf
```

The `-l 10` option to `svn log` limits the output to the 10 most recent log entries -- customize that as you wish, or customize the output with other options.

The next step would be to write a shell script or other small program that would filter the log to show just the most recent changes, generate diffs for the changed files, and wrap that all up into a PDF for you to review. As you can see from the above, the tools you'd need to do that are already there -- you just need to put them together in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a DVCS which consists in having the whole repository, with its whole history, on every "client" machine. SVN is a centralized VCS, where the working copy only has the latest version of every file. The history is only available on the server.

If offline work is so important, git is obviously a much better choice, and you should switch to git. I don't think any SVN tool will ever give you access to previous versions offline, because that's just not how SVN works.